# I keep getting "expected an indented block" when running my python code on idle

Tags: python

**This is it.**

```
while userInputValid != True: 
            try:
print("Welcome to Domino's Pizza Uganda! SUPA PIZZA!!! DIRECT FROM WAKALIWOOD ZULUL Where SUPA-PACKED movies are made!")
region = input("What is your region? \n 1.) Central\n 2.) Western \n 3.) Eastern\n 4.) Northern\n\n")

print ("Region:", region, "selected!\n\n")


if region == 1 or region == 2 or region == 3 or region == 4:
      userInputValid = True

else:
      print("Unexpected number! Please choose numbers 1, 2, 3 or 4.")

except ValueError:
      print("Numbers only please!\n Single digits like 1, 2, 3 or 4.")

      if region == 1:
            print("Central region selected! \n\n")
             if region == 2:
                   print("Western region selected! \n\n")
                   if region == 3:
                         print("Eastern region selected! \n\n")
                         if region == 4:
                               print("Northern region selected! \n\n")

pickupdelivery = input("Pick-up or SUPA Delivery?!\n \n 1 = Pick-up. \n 2 = SUPA DELIVERY!")



print(pickupdelivery, "picked!")
```

**I have no idea whats wrong with it**

Comment: Everything between the `try:` and the `except:` has to be indented to the right of the word `try`.

Comment: You might start with https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

Comment: Not what's causing the error, but I'm pretty sure that all those `if region == ...` statements should all be on the same indentation level. Otherwise there's no possibility of any but the first `print` statement being hit.

Comment: The `print` after the `try:` is wrong on its face. You can't have an *outdent* after a line that ends in syntax that's supposed to start a block.

Comment: ...not to mention that all the code that's supposed to be repeated in the `while:` loop needs to be indented a level, and that's not being done here either.

Answer (score 0):

White space defined structure in python which is what makes it, generally, more readable than many other languages. However that makes it very important that you pay attention to the indentation. Get one line at the wrong indent level can either cause errors, or worse act differently than you expected.

I would also **encourage** you to run flake8 (http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) on your code which will pick up a lot of mistakes and formatting errors before you get to the code-running stage.

I believe that you want it to look more like this:

```
while userInputValid != True:
    try:
        print("Welcome to Domino's Pizza Uganda! SUPA PIZZA!!! DIRECT FROM WAKALIWOOD ZULUL Where SUPA-PACKED movies are made!")
        region = input("What is your region? \n 1.) Central\n 2.) Western \n 3.) Eastern\n 4.) Northern\n\n")

        print ("Region:", region, "selected!\n\n")

        if region == 1 or region == 2 or region == 3 or region == 4:
              userInputValid = True
        else:
              print("Unexpected number! Please choose numbers 1, 2, 3 or 4.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Numbers only please!\n Single digits like 1, 2, 3 or 4.")

    if region == 1:
        print("Central region selected! \n\n")
    if region == 2:
        print("Western region selected! \n\n")
    if region == 3:
        print("Eastern region selected! \n\n")
    if region == 4:  
        print("Northern region selected! \n\n")
    pickupdelivery = input("Pick-up or SUPA Delivery?!\n \n 1 = Pick-up. \n 2 = SUPA DELIVERY!")
    print(pickupdelivery, "picked!")
```